# Making C++ pause

Tags: c++, python, time, sleep

Is there a C++ equivalent to Python's **time.sleep()**?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [boost::this_thread::sleep](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread.sleep)

```
// sleep for 5 seconds
boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
```

Comment: Though, of course, boost may just not be an option for this person.

Comment: @Omnifarious: That's possible.  But unless the OP specifically states otherwise, I see no reason to assume that boost is not an option.  Every C++ developer should have boost installed, if possible.

Comment: Since we don't know what OS the OP is using, the Boost solution is really the one that's most likely to work.

Answer (score 5):

The following code will sleep for 10 milliseconds.

`boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10))`

Refer to [boost::posix_time::time_duration](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#date_time.posix_time.time_duration) for more ways to construct the duration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any portable function, but mainstream OSes have [`usleep`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep) for *nix and [`Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298.aspx) for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the code above was tested on Code::Blocks 12.11 and Visual Studio 2012
on Windows 7.

**For forcing your programme stop or wait, you have several options :**

---

- **sleep(unsigned int)**

The value has to be a positive integer in millisecond.
That means that if you want your programme wait for 2 second, enter 2000.

Here's an example :

```
#include <iostream>     //for using cout
#include <stdlib.h>     //for using the function sleep

using namespace std;    //for using cout

int main(void)         
{
   cout << "test" << endl;
   sleep(5000);         //make the programme waiting for 5 secondes
   cout << "test" << endl;
   sleep(2000);         // wait for 2 secondes before closing

   return 0;
}
```

If you wait too long, that probably means the parameter is in second. So change it like that :

```
sleep(5);
```

For those who get error message or problem using sleep try to replace it by _sleep or Sleep especially on Code::Bloks.
And if you still getting probleme, try to add of one this library on the biggining of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

---

- **system("PAUSE")**

A simple "Hello world" programme on windows console application would probably close before you can see anything. That the case where you can use system("Pause").

```
#include <iostream>    

using namespace std;   

int main(void)         
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

If you get the message "error: 'system' was not declared in this scope" just add 
the following line at the biggining of the code :

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

---

- **cin.ignore()**

The same result can be reached by using cin.ignore() :

```
#include <iostream>     

using namespace std;    

int main(void)         
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

---

- **cin.get()**

example :

```
#include <iostream>     

using namespace std;    

int main(void)         
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

---

- **getch()**

Just don't forget to add the library conio.h :

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <conio.h>    //for using the function getch()

using namespace std;    

int main(void)
{

    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

You can have message telling you to use _getch() insted of getch